# Flow router and filtering roles - Meteor

Tags: meteor, roles, flow-router

I'm dealing with one problem more than 10 days now, and I don't know what to do with it, so I hope that I'll get my solution here.

I have two roles 'admin' and 'user': the first user is added as the admin thanks to the alanning:roles package. However, the problem is that I'm not sure if I set the 'user' role as default.

The picture below shows the code for the createUser function.

**Client//Account//account.js**

```
Template.signup.events({
  'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var nameVar =  event.target.signupName.value;
    var emailVar = event.target.signupEmail.value;
    var passwordVar = event.target.signupPassword.value;

    Accounts.createUser({
      name: nameVar,
      email: emailVar,
      password: passwordVar,
      profile: {
        roles: ["user"]
      } 

     });
  }
});
```

And below code is the Accounts.onLogin function:

**Client//Lib//routes.js**

```
if (Meteor.user().roles = 'admin'){
  FlowRouter.go('dashboard');
}

else if (Meteor.user().roles = 'user'){
    FlowRouter.go('account');
}
```

I hope that you understand what my problem is and I looking forward the solution. In conclusion, I need to have 'admin' and 'user' role, and when it is admin it should go to */admin-dashboard* route, if it is user it should go to */account* route.

Thank you all :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
if (Meteor.user().roles = 'admin'){ // assigning, not equality check
  FlowRouter.go('dashboard');
}

else if (Meteor.user().roles = 'user'){
    FlowRouter.go('account');
}
```

But `roles` field is an array, so do this instead:

```
if (Meteor.user().roles.indexOf('admin') !== -1){
  FlowRouter.go('dashboard');
}

else if (Meteor.user().roles.indexOf('user') !== -1){
    FlowRouter.go('account');
}
```

Comment: For now my 'admin-dashboard' route works good, thank you :D  However, the 'user' role part doesn't work because I didn't set it as default. I tried this: function myCreateUser (email, password, name) {
    var id,
        defaultRoles = ['default', 'user'];

    id = Accounts.createUser({
      email: email,
      password: password,
    });

    Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, defaultRoles);
} But when I call this method on client site it's like it doesn't exist.

Comment: Instead of direct check, consider using [`userIsInRole`](http://alanning.github.io/meteor-roles/classes/Roles.html#method_userIsInRole) method. And if there's no default role, just add `else` block with `FlowRouter.go('somewhere')` inside.